# How does the python function int() work such that it produces strange anomalies?

Tags: python, int

Why does the following statement in Python output the integer 19 rather than 20?

```
int((11.20-11)*100)
```

I  believe there is something about the int function that I do not know about. How is the int function programmed such that the above line of code outputs 19?

Comment: Because `0.20` cannot be accurately represented in floating point.

Comment: Check the output of 11.20-11, and you'll find its `0.1999999999999993`

Comment: Why does that happen?

Comment: Maybe this documentation could help: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Or this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I suggest learning about "floating point" numbers.  In this case, 0.20 cannot be exactly represented as a finite sum of powers of two, so its representation is an approximation, not exact.  This is true in any computer language that supports floating point numbers.